# Save Hubspot Form Submission Data on Local

Tags: wordpress, hubspot

I am using wordpress, on a page showing hubspot form using javascript code provided by hubspot.

What I want is to save the counter of how many times form is submitted.

As I checked in Network tool of chrome,

```
email: example@example.com
phone: 1234567890
firstname: example
lastname: exmaple
company: 
address:
```

like this data is getting sent and response is 200.

Example Request URL:

```
https://forms.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/public/submit/formsnext/multipart/9726307/91a9604-1cd5-46aa-a3e1-3399f55d8c43
```

It looks like, this is not an Ajax call, so can someone suggest how can I track it?

Comment: I was trying to use AJAX with it, but it looks like this is not an AJAX call, no AJAX action is there, so I am not getting a way to run ajax whenever this Submission occurs.

Comment: Isn't the number of times the form submitted = the number of inquiries you received in HubSpot?

You can check your HubSpot account and get the count.

Comment: How is this submission handled otherwise? Is there any chance you can share more details, like the code involved?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods for doing this that I can think of:

- If you have access to the HubSpot account: create a workflow/webhook that will call a PHP file and that will increment that counter for you.
- If you don't have access to the HubSpot account: use the [onFormSubmit](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options) event in the embed code. It is something like:

  ```
  onFormSubmit: function($form) {
    // call a PHP file that will increment the counter for you
    }
  ```